# Lock the records using salesforce code

Tags: apex

I am trying to lock the records through below code,but i did not find any lock symbol on layout.I am able to edit the records after locking also.I want to lock the records after insert in trigger.

```
// Query the accounts to lock
Case [] cases = [SELECT Id from Case];
// Lock the accounts
Approval.LockResult[] lrList = Approval.lock(cases, false);

// Iterate through each returned result
for(Approval.LockResult lr : lrList) {
    if (lr.isSuccess()) {
        // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
        System.debug('Successfully locked account with ID: ' + lr.getId());
    }
    else {
        // Operation failed, so get all errors                
        for(Database.Error err : lr.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
            System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
            System.debug('Case fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you enable record locking and unlocking in Apex under `Process Automation Settings`.

Admin and Approval can edit the records even it is locked.

Comment: ya i enabled the option under process automation settings.as a user also lock button is not showing up and the user also able to edit the record even after locking

Comment: add this Case[] cases= [SELECT Id FROM case LIMIT 2 FOR UPDATE]; This locks the records from updating

Comment: @ambitiousinme `FOR UPDATE` establishes a record lock only for the duration of the Apex transaction.

Comment: @DavidReed That's correct